# Slow queue tailer on multi-threaded appenders queue

Tags: java, multithreading, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have scenario where multiple threads are writing to the same queue.

Appender threads receive updates from the different markets (each thread single market) and push those data into same queue:

```
ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path + "/market").build();
        final ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();
appender.writeDocument(
                        wire -> {

                                wire
                                        .getValueOut().text("buy")
                                        .getValueOut().text(exchange.name())
                                        .getValueOut().text(currencyPair.toString())
                                        .getValueOut().dateTime(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()))
                                        .getValueOut().text(price);
                            });
```

Then I have completely separate process(different JVM) to continuously read from the queue by doing:

```
while (true){
     tailer.readDocument(........
```

But while I generate about 10 updates to the queue per second, the tailer process about one record per 3 seconds. I think I am missing something fundamental here :-)

Or what is the correct way to continuously listen for updates on the queue? I wasn't able to find any other solution than while (true) then do...

I am developing on 18-core machine (36 threads) and use Java Affinity to assign each work to itc own CPU.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a queue is very expensive, try to only do this once per process if you can.

Creating a Tailer is also expensive, you should create this once and keep polling for the updates.

Creating objects can be expensive, I would avoid creating any objects. e.g. avoid calling `toString` or `LocalDate.now`

Here is an example of benchmarking

```
String path = OS.getTarget();
ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path + "/market").build();
ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
Exchange exchange = Exchange.EBS;
CurrencyPair currencyPair = CurrencyPair.EURUSD;
double price = 1.2345;
for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int messages = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < messages; i++) {
        try (DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
            ValueOut valueOut = dc.wire().getValueOut();
            valueOut.text("buy")
                    .getValueOut().asEnum(exchange)
                    .getValueOut().asEnum(currencyPair)
                    .getValueOut().int64(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .getValueOut().float64(price);
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Throughput was %,d messages per second%n", (long) (messages * 1e9 / time));
    Jvm.pause(100);
}
```

prints

```
Throughput was 962,942 messages per second
Throughput was 2,952,433 messages per second
Throughput was 4,776,337 messages per second
Throughput was 3,250,235 messages per second
Throughput was 3,514,863 messages per second
```

And for reading you can do

```
final ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();
for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int messages = 100000;
    for (int i = 0; i < messages; i++) {
        try (DocumentContext dc = tailer.readingDocument()) {
            if (!dc.isPresent())
                throw new AssertionError("Missing t: " + t + ", i: " + i);
            ValueIn in = dc.wire().getValueIn();
            String buy = in.text();
            Exchange exchange2 = in.asEnum(Exchange.class);
            CurrencyPair currencyPair2 = in.asEnum(CurrencyPair.class);
            long time = in.int64();
            double price2 = in.float64();
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Read Throughput was %,d messages per second%n", (long) (messages * 1e9 / time));
}
```

note: it reads the same number of messages as were written.

prints

```
Read Throughput was 477,849 messages per second
Read Throughput was 3,083,642 messages per second
Read Throughput was 5,100,516 messages per second
Read Throughput was 6,342,525 messages per second
Read Throughput was 6,672,971 messages per second
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your great stuff first of all. Thanks for piece of code. The problem I see is on the tailer. In short I don't see on tailer end all messages I put into the queue via appender threads(or I am under impression in the moment), it looks to me like once per time I get the latest available, is it possible or even standard behaviour (kind of configuration of tailer)? I use 4.6.61 version of the queue. I have simply much more appends then later tail events in numbers, but I need to check fully the queue dump, but numbers of events RX/TX are completely different.

Comment: Anyway you are deadly high performance warrior when I look at openhft stuff :-), thanks again for such great project being public.

Comment: @kensai I have added a read example, which read all the messages at a rate of up to 6.6m/s. Without seeing your code, I can't guess what is wrong.

Comment: Brilliant, well, my code is really using just pure while (true) { tailer.readDocument } in infinite loop as suggested in original statement. I didn't use the DocumentContext object at all. I am going to give it a try. I actually used following code example: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue-Sample/blob/master/simple-input/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/simple/input/OutputMain.java

Comment: do you consider something like @Producer(queue name, location or config) @Consumer(queue name, location or config) or something like this to be implemented underlying, so I can work with Chronicle queue as with asynchronous broker system.

Comment: @kensai we favour supporting asynchronous APIs as a more natural way to code in Java. https://vanilla-java.github.io/2016/03/24/Microservices-in-the-Chronicle-world-Part-2.html